# Why was this character killed?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

**Warning: This question contains massive spoilers about Alice in Borderland: Season 2. If you have not watched this season to the end yet, read on your own risk.**

The final game Arisu and Usagi participate in, the Queen of Hearts, is explained (by Mira, the Queen of Hearts, herself) to have the following rules:

- It doesn't matter who wins.
- You just have to complete three sets of croquet games without withdrawing.
- If you decide to give up, game over.

In the end, the requirements are fulfilled and all participants (Arisu on behalf of the players, and Mira on behalf of the game masters) finish three rounds of croquet ... and then, Mira gets killed by the laser.

**Why did she get killed?**

Some thoughts:

- She was noticeably informal during reciting of the rules, much more so than the rule declarations in the other games. Maybe she left out the specifics of what a win for the players would mean?
- It is kind of in line with the other face card games, given that the other citizens that lead games were killed when the players won, as well.

Still, I am confused by it. After all, if the implication is that all game masters are always killed when a player clears a game, what could possibly be the motivation for anyone to stay in Borderland, becoming a citizen (and thereby, presumably, a game master)?

Comment: To me, that is the most disturbing implication of the setting: the people represented by the face cards are ordinary players who have become so enamored of Borderland that the games really are almost all that matter to them. Win or lose, they enjoy playing the game, *even if it means their own death*. The Queen of Hearts, the King and Queen of Spades, and the King of Clubs (and his team) were all almost as happy to lose as to win, and even the King of Diamonds seemed to make his peace with it at the end. Only the Jack of Hearts seemed worried about losing.

Comment: @Adamant: Maybe that's a reasonable interpretation. While watching the show, I considered all of those Queens/Kings as examples of (caution, TVTropes link ahead!) [Fair-Play Villains](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FairPlayVillain); villains that, despite all their ruthlessness, would strictly stick to the rules they set for their game, even if it meant the players would win eventually. This seemed to become most explicit for the King of Diamonds, but would be reflected by your observation. It does somewhat conflict with the impression that it might be primarily the "lost ...

Comment: ... and lawless" that might be most likely to decide to stay in Borderland. Then, of course, the skyborne lasers might actually ensure that tweaking the rules once they have been set is not a desirable option for the game master, either.

Comment: That might be true of the King of Diamonds, certainly. But the Queen of Spades, Queen of Hearts, and King of Clubs were simply far too neutral upon losing. The Queen of Hearts even seemed a little excited that Usagi and Arisu had managed to win! And of course, if there is nothing requiring them to make these games in the first place, I think their obsession with them is clear from the fact that they choose to voluntarily risk their lives and those of others in them instead of just...not doing it. We saw that the only people to become citizens at the end were people who saw Borderland as pure.

Comment: Although I think the question of how much control the citizens really have is certainly open. After all, apart from the Queen of Hearts and her power to seemingly control people's perceptions, none of the others demonstrate having any capabilities beyond the mundane. They certainly are not creating magic sky lasers and complicated death traps with a handful of normal people, and I certainly doubt the face cards can send people back to the living world once they are dead. The citizens may well still be subject to rules or forces beyond their control.